# Top Shelf giving an error Sequence contains more than one element

Tags: topshelf

I am trying to host a console application as window service using top shelf here is the code :

```
RunConfiguration cfg = RunnerConfigurator.New(x =>
{
   x.ConfigureService<Certegy>(s =>
   {
       s.Named("certegy");
       s.HowToBuildService(name => new Certegy());
       s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());
       s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());
    });
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[1]))
    {
        x.RunAsLocalSystem();
        }
    else
    {
        x.RunAs(args[1], args[2]);
    }

    x.SetDescription("Certegy host to get the messages from the queue");
    x.SetDisplayName("Certegy Interface");
    x.SetServiceName("Certegy Interface");
});

   Runner.Host(cfg, args);
```

From command line i am running as :

```
ExeName install username password
```

I am getting an error `{"Sequence contains more than one element"}` in last line

```
Runner.Host(cfg, args);
```

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Topshelf are you using?

The username and password via the command line has not been working in a while, if you grab the latest development code from Chris, who added this feature, at https://github.com/phatboyg/Topshelf/tree/develop I think it has been addressed, otherwise just set it in the code to read from an app.config for the time being.

Comment: Thanks Travis for your inputs..!